# How do I turn on page numbering with classicthesis?

Tags: page-numbering, classicthesis

How do I turn on page numbering with `classicthesis`?

I'm using TeXworks, with the pdfLaTeX setting.  Here's what I have so far:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{book}
 \usepackage{classicthesis}

 \begin{document}
 \title{Book Title}
 \author{My Name}
 \maketitle

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Introduction}
 \section{This Document}
 This is some text.
 \end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there some other command I need to use to turn on page numbering?

Comment: @Sigur, that doesn't do it.  Filling it with pages of lorem ipsum still leaves it without page numbers.

Comment: @Sigur, so what should I be doing instead?

Comment: Just do `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}` or `\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}`

Comment: @Sigur, I need it to be on letter-sized paper (8.5" x 11").  Is `letterpaper` the wrong way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `letterpaper` paper option passed to the `book` class.

The text height is too large and then the page number is hidden.

Since you really need that paper size, load the `geometry` package *after* `classicthesis` and pass the option to it.

```
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
```

[image]